Degrees of freedom in a likelihood ratio test - multivariate normal vs univariate normal and Archimedean copula
Hopefully the title is self explanatory! To be more specific, I have three datasets.  First, I fit them to a multivariate normal distribution, and calculate the log-likelihood.  Then, I fit normal marginals and a (say) Clayton copula, and sum the log-likelihoods of the marginal and copula fits.  The log-likelihood of the latter is higher than the former.  To see whether the improvement is significant, I'd use a likelihood ratio test.  But what would my degrees of freedom be?
